# Magento 2 Custom Validation Rule

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, validation

I want to validate a custom-category-attribute with regex, when I modify it in backend. Therefor I want to customize validation/rules.js

```
src/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/lib/validation/rules.js
```

But when i save the category the validation check, won't be executed.

**src/app/code/Xyz/Base/view/adminhtml/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
  config: {
    mixins: {
        'Magento_Ui/js/lib/validation/rule': {
            'Xyz/js/rules-mixin': true
        }
    }
  }
}
```

**src/app/code/Xyz/Base/view/adminhtml/web/js/rules-mixin.js**

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'moment'
], function ($, moment) {
  'use strict';

  return function (validator) {

    validator.addRule(
        'validate-warehouse-number',
        function (value, params, additionalParams) {
            return /^([0-9]{2}(?:\|[0-9]{2})*)?$/.test(value);
        },
        $.mage.__("Warehouse Number must have two diggest with a | as separtor")
    );

    return validator;
  };
});
```

Usage:

**src/app/code/Xyz/Base/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml**

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<fieldset name="warehouse">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Warehouse</item>
            <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">100</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <field name="warehouse_number">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Warehouse Number</item>
                <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <scopeLabel>[WEBSITE]</scopeLabel>
            <validation>
                <rule name="validate-warehouse-number" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
            </validation>
            <label translate="true">Warehouse Number</label>
            <dataScope>warehouse_number</dataScope>
        </settings>
    </field>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Has somebody an idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution: rules-mixin.js must be validator-mixin.js

```
var config = {
  config: {
    mixins: {
        'Magento_Ui/js/lib/validation/validator': {
            'Xyz_Base/js/validator-mixin': true
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: could you please help me on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/319106/magento2-restrict-cc-number-in-the-form-fields

Answer (score 1):

To add a custom validation for ui forms

1. Create your custom-validation.js file inside the **/app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/web/js/** directory

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'jquery/ui',
    'jquery/validate',
    'mage/translate'
    ], function($){
        'use strict';
        return function() {
            $.validator.addMethod(
                "custom-validation",
                function(value, element) {
                    //Perform your operation here and return the result true/false.
                    return true/false;
                },
                $.mage.__("Your validation message.")
            );
    }
});
```

2. Add your js file in routename_customform_edit.xml file inside the **magento-root-dir/app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/ directory**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="styles"/>
    <head>
        <link src="Vendor_Module::js/custom-validation.js"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="ui_component_form"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

3. Add your custom validation rule named custom-validation” in the store_url field in the ui_component_form.xml file as follows

```
<field name="store_url">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Store URL</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">store_url</item>
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="notice" xsi:type="string" translate="true">
                       Enter store URL name. For example: xyzshop
                    </item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <strong><item name="custom-validation" xsi:type="boolean">true</item></strong>
                        <item name="validate-no-html-tags" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
```